# Refactor the button function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, refactoring

I have many of this button function, the only differenct is the GameObject[] through the singleton.

Like this

```
public void Oneselect()
{
   GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayOne; 
  dosomething();
}
public void Twoselect()
{
   GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayTwo;
  dosomething();
}
.
.
.
public void Tenselect()
{
   GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayTen;
  dosomething();
}
```

How can i refactor this, like only use one function?

Comment: Use an array of arrays `GameObject[][]` and then access `Manager.singleton.arrays[x]` where the x is something you could make the buttons pass into your method ... depends  bit how exactly you set this up ... if yo attach the listeners via code you can do it fully dynamic ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this like that

```
        public void onSelect(int selectedAmount){
   switch (selectedAmount)
        {
        case 1:
                GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayOne;

             break;
        case 2:
               GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayTwo;

            break;
        case 10:
               GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayTen;

            break;
//optional
        default:
               GameObject[] typeor = Manager.singleton.arrayTwo;

            break;
        }
}
```

and call it like `onSelect(HOW MANY SELECTED);`

Comment: You can write this easier as `GameObject[] typeor = selectedAmount switch { 1 =>  Manager.singleton.arrayOne, 2 => Manager.singleton.arrayTwo, 10 => Manager.singleton.arrayTen, _ => Manager.singleton.arrayTwo};`